# Is it possible to avoid nested RetryLoop.callWithRetry calls so I get a consistent timeout?

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

I've configured a reasonable timeout using BoundedExponentialBackoffRetry, and generally it works as I'd expect if ZK is down when I make a call like "create.forPath". But if ZK is unavailable when I call acquire on an InterProcessReadWriteLock, it takes far longer before it finally times out.

I call acquire which is wrapped in "RetryLoop.callWithRetry" and it goes onto call findProtectedNodeInForeground which is also wrapped in "RetryLoop.callWithRetry". If I've configured the BoundedExponentialBackoffRetry to retry 20 times, the inner retry tries 20 times for every one of the 20 outer retry loops, so it retries 400 times.

We really need a consistent timeout after which we fail. Have I done anything wrong / anyway around this? If not, I guess I'll call the troublesome methods in a new thread that I can kill after my own timeout.

Here is the sample code to recreate it. I stick break points at the lines following the comments, bring ZK down and then let it continue and take the stacktrace whilst it's re-trying.

```
public class GoCurator {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    CuratorFramework cf = CuratorFrameworkFactory.newClient(
            "localhost:2181",
            new BoundedExponentialBackoffRetry(200, 10000, 20)
    );
    cf.start();

    String root = "/myRoot";
    if(cf.checkExists().forPath(root) == null) {
        // Stacktrace A showing what happens if ZK is down for this call
        cf.create().forPath(root);
    }

    InterProcessReadWriteLock lcok = new InterProcessReadWriteLock(cf, "/grant/myLock");

    // See stacktrace B showing the nested re-try if ZK is down for this call
    lcok.readLock().acquire();

    lcok.readLock().release();

    System.out.println("done");
}
```

}

Stacktrace A (if ZK is down when I'm calling create().forPath). This shows the single retry loop so it exist after the correct number of attempts:

```
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
  at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn.submitRequest(ClientCnxn.java:1499)
  at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn.submitRequest(ClientCnxn.java:1487)
  at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.getChildren(ZooKeeper.java:2617)
  at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.GetChildrenBuilderImpl$3.call(GetChildrenBuilderImpl.java:242)
  at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.GetChildrenBuilderImpl$3.call(GetChildrenBuilderImpl.java:231)
  at org.apache.curator.connection.StandardConnectionHandlingPolicy.callWithRetry(StandardConnectionHandlingPolicy.java:64)
  at org.apache.curator.RetryLoop.callWithRetry(RetryLoop.java:100)
  at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.GetChildrenBuilderImpl.pathInForeground(GetChildrenBuilderImpl.java:228)
  at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.GetChildrenBuilderImpl.forPath(GetChildrenBuilderImpl.java:219)
  at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.GetChildrenBuilderImpl.forPath(GetChildrenBuilderImpl.java:41)
  at com.gebatech.curator.GoCurator.main(GoCurator.java:25)
```

Stacktrace B (if ZK is down when I call InterProcessReadWriteLock#readLock#acquire). This shows the nested re-try loop so it doesn't exit until 20*20 attempts.

```
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:-1)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1037)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.tryAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1328)
  at java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.await(CountDownLatch.java:277)
  at org.apache.curator.CuratorZookeeperClient.internalBlockUntilConnectedOrTimedOut(CuratorZookeeperClient.java:434)
  at org.apache.curator.connection.StandardConnectionHandlingPolicy.callWithRetry(StandardConnectionHandlingPolicy.java:56)
  at org.apache.curator.RetryLoop.callWithRetry(RetryLoop.java:100)
  at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl.findProtectedNodeInForeground(CreateBuilderImpl.java:1239)
  at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl.access$1700(CreateBuilderImpl.java:51)
  at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl$17.call(CreateBuilderImpl.java:1167)
  at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl$17.call(CreateBuilderImpl.java:1156)
  at org.apache.curator.connection.StandardConnectionHandlingPolicy.callWithRetry(StandardConnectionHandlingPolicy.java:64)
  at org.apache.curator.RetryLoop.callWithRetry(RetryLoop.java:100)
  at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl.pathInForeground(CreateBuilderImpl.java:1153)
  at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl.protectedPathInForeground(CreateBuilderImpl.java:607)
  at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl.forPath(CreateBuilderImpl.java:597)
  at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl.forPath(CreateBuilderImpl.java:575)
  at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl.forPath(CreateBuilderImpl.java:51)
  at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.locks.StandardLockInternalsDriver.createsTheLock(StandardLockInternalsDriver.java:54)
  at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.locks.LockInternals.attemptLock(LockInternals.java:225)
  at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.locks.InterProcessMutex.internalLock(InterProcessMutex.java:237)
  at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.locks.InterProcessMutex.acquire(InterProcessMutex.java:89)
  at com.gebatech.curator.GoCurator.main(GoCurator.java:29)
```

Comment: I've raised a Jira for this and it didn't get knocked back, so I'll proceed with a work around for now

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CURATOR-559

Answer (score 0):

This turns out to be a real, longstanding, problem with how Curator uses retries. I have a fix and PR ready here: https://github.com/apache/curator/pull/346 - I'd appreciate more eyes on it.